# How to tell flask to random picture from directory everytime user refresh web page?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Currently I am using flask and heroku to deploy my website but i need my webpage show random photo from img directory currently my code look like this

```
import os
import random
imgs = os.listdir('static/img')
imgs = ['img/' + file for file in imgs]
imgrand = random.sample(imgs,k=5)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', imgrand=imgrand)
```

And my HTML code look like this

```
{% for img in imgrand %}
<img src="static/{{img}}" alt="{{imgL}}" style="width:100%">
{% endfor %}
```

So long it work fine in my local machine ,but it only random picture only once when start `flask run` command in terminal. My goal is to make my web page random picture everytime when refresh webpage without going to end terminal session and start `flask run` command all over again.

Comment: Please do the sampling in the function which issues call to render the html.

Comment: If you perform a `CTRL + F5` the picture is being changed?

Comment: @CCebrian No it is not, It only change when I end my terminal session and run flask again

Comment: Did you try to put `imgrand = random.sample(imgs,k=5)` inside of the `index()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case `imggrand` variable only takes one sample at the beggining of the program, for repeating the process everytime you refresh the webpage you need to put `imggrand` inside the endpoint.

I recommend you to learn about endpoints and designing the workflow starting with this: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates

Comment: Thank you. Working after put `imgrand` under `index()`